# Error when trying to build logical parser

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So i have these strings stored in database and i want to convert them to python expression to use them with if statement. I will store these strings into list and will loop over them.
For example:

```
string = "#apple and @banana or @grapes"
```

i am able to convert this string by replacing # with "a==" and @ with "b==" to this :

```
if a == apple and b == banana or b == grapes
```

hash refers to a
@ refers to b

But when i use eval it throws up error "apple is not defined" because apple is not in quotes. so what i want is this:

```
if a == "apple" and b == "banana" or b == "grapes"
```

Is there any way i can do this ?
The strings stored in DB can have any type of format, can have multiple and/or conditions.

Few examples:

```
string[0] = "#apple and @banana or @grapes"
string[1] = "#apple or @banana and @grapes"
string[2] = "#apple and @banana and @grapes"
```

There will be else condition where no condition is fullfilled

Thanks

Comment: how did you convert to `if a == apple and b == banana`?

Comment: @HarshaBiyani by simply replacing # with "a ==".and also i can convert it to dict  like this {"a":"apple"}

Comment: Split your string into a list by a control character. From your example a simple `string.split('and')` would yield a list made up of `['#apple', '#banana']`. From there you can call comparisons on individual list element.

Comment: Please edit it to first state your **real** problem, and then how you though the code above would help you solve it.

Comment: Will the `or` always appear between words starting with the same character? For example is `#apple and #banna` impossible? What about `#apple or @banaa`? The first does not make sense but is an option , but the second definitely seems legitimate. Also, please edit the question to say what should happen in the `if`? `a` and `b` do not exist, so what would be the point of setting `a='apple'` and then asking `if a=='apple'`?

Comment: OK, so `string[2]` should always yield a false result (a equals apply and b equals banana and b equals grapes) if I understand correctly?

Comment: i am really sorry.can i update the question once again?because i am getting multiple a's and b's from my other function.like a_list= ["apple","america"] etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are trying so setup something of a logical parser - you want to evaluate if the expression can possibly be true, or not.

```
@word or @otherword
```

is always true since it's possible to satisfy this with `@=word` for example, but

```
@word and @otherword
```

is not since it is impossible to satisfy this. The way you were going is using Python's builtin interpreter, but you seem to "make up" variables `a` and `b`, which do not exist. Just to give you a starter for such a parser, here is one bad implementation:

```
from itertools import product
def test(string):
    var_dict   = {}
    word_dict  = {}
    cur_var    = ord('a')
    expression = []
    for i,w in enumerate(string.split()):
        if not i%2:
            if w[0] not in var_dict:
                var_dict[w[0]] = chr(cur_var)
                word_dict[var_dict[w[0]]] = []
                cur_var += 1
            word_dict[var_dict[w[0]]].append(w[1:])
            expression.append('{}=="{}"'.format(var_dict[w[0]],w[1:]))
        else: expression.append(w)
    expression = ' '.join(expression)

    result = {}
    for combination in product(
        *([(v,w) for w in word_dict[v]] for v in word_dict)): 
        exec(';'.join('{}="{}"'.format(v,w) for v,w in combination)+';value='+expression,globals(),result)
        if result['value']: return True
    return False
```

Beyond not checking if the string is valid, this is not great, but a place to start grasping what you're after.

What this does is create your expression in the first loop, while saving a hash mapping the first characters of words (`w[0]`) to variables named from a to z (if you want more you need to do better than `cur_var+=1`). It also maps each such variable to all the words it was assigned to in the original expression (`word_dict`).

The second loop runs a pretty bad algorithm - `product` will give all the possible paring of variable and matching word, and I iterate each combination and assign our fake variables the words in an `exec` command. There are plenty of reasons to avoid `exec`, but this is easiest for setting the variables. If I found a combination that satisfies the expression, I return True, otherwise False. You cannot use `eval` if you want to assign stuff (or for `if,for,while` etc.).

Not this can drastically be improved on by writing your own logical parser to read the string, though it will probably be longer.

```
#Evaluted as (#apple and @banana) or @grapes) by Python - only #=apple @=banana satisfies this.
>>> test("#apple and @banana or @grapes")
True
#Evaluted as #apple or (@banana and @grapes) by Python - all combinations satisfy this as @ does not matter.
>>> test("#apple or @banana and @grapes") 
True
#demands both @=banana and @=grapes - impossible.
>>> test("#apple and @banana and @grapes")
False
```

Comment: Thanks. This is somewhat what i was looking for.Sorry for being not clear enough.This will surely help me get started. And also can you explain what the second loop is doing. what exactly is product variable?

Comment: @RahulSingh Sorry, forgot the import line- I edited it above the function. It creates all possible combinations from each list. Use print(combination) in the loop to see what it did for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of what you are asking here, but you can use the `replace` and `split` functions :

```
string = "#apple and #banana"
fruits = string.replace("#", "").split("and")
if a == fruits[0] and b == fruits[1]:
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. i Have kinda tried this already. conditions are not static